# Active Directory on AWS Instance to join Local On Premise desktops/laptops

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, cloud

Is it Possible to have Active Directory On AWS without On-Premise Active Directory?

I wanted to join my on-premise users desktop/laptop to Active Directory On AWS .

Basically, i do not want to have on-premise Active Directory.

Comment: You should move this question to a more suitable location [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

We have AD/DNS servers in AWS in a trusted forest, and although our laptops don't join those domains there is no reason they can't.  We can logon from our local machines using the forest user credentials no issue.

If you are using Windows Server then ensure your DHCP Options for clients point to your Windows Server running DNS and that the relevant ports for AD are open on the security groups/NACLs.

Comment: For example, i created my own MS AD on AWS by using Directory Service.
I guess i have to set up a VPN in order to join that domain, right?

Comment: Yes, you need a way to communicate with the cloud AD instance, either Direct Connect or VPN.